# Post form inputs as seperate arrays

Tags: html, arrays, forms

I have an arbitrary number of 'rows' of data that I need to post via a form, to achieve the following array structure, so that `impact_speed` will then contain x number of arrays, each of which contains a `description`, `value` and `unit` element:

```
array(1) {
  ["impact_speed"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(3) "one"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["unit"]=>
      string(3) "mph"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(3) "two"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "20"
      ["unit"]=>
      string(3) "kph"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(5) "three"
      ["value"]=>
      string(2) "30"
      ["unit"]=>
      string(3) "fps"
    }
  }
}
```

If the number of rows was fixed, I could achieve this by indexing my form inputs like so:

```
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[0][description]" value="one">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[0][value]" value="10">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[0][unit]" value="mph">

<input type="text" name="impact_speed[1][description]" value="two">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[1][value]" value="20">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[1][unit]" value="kph">

<input type="text" name="impact_speed[2][description]" value="three">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[2][value]" value="30">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[2][unit]" value="fps">
```

however, I am adding these using a javascript UI which allows a user to click a plus icon to create a new row, so I don't have a fixed number of rows to work with.

eg if I don't specify index numbers like in the following example, it obviously creates three separate arrays per row, which is not what I want:

```
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[][description]" value="three">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[][value]" value="30">
<input type="text" name="impact_speed[][unit]" value="fps">
```

Is there a way of naming my form inputs without having to dynamically insert the index numbers (0,1,2 etc) ?

Comment: What does your Javascript look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up indexing my arrays, as I realised it was the only practical way of doing this. I then increment the index each time a row is added. Here is an example of the code used to increment the index, after the row is cloned.

```js
// If the input names contain an array index, we need to increment it:
$newRow.find('input, select').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/, function(match, capture) {
    return '[' + (parseInt(capture, 10) + 1) + ']' ; 
  }));
});
```